# What is the best translation for 'Application Spontanée' (french)

Tags: expressions, translation, french

I'm trying to find how I could translate 'Application Spontanée' from french.

Is there an expression in english to talk about when you apply at an employer, but without any attached open job offer?

Comment: If you refer to a "candidature spontanée'", you may translate it to unsolicited/spontaneous [job] application, *cf @YosefBaskin answer*.

Comment: A simple, yet **extremely good answer** proposing [“**speculative application**”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/speculative-application) was unfortunately deleted overnight. If it was deleted prior to you having been given the opportunity to see it, you might want to consider [that term as well](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speculative+application%2Cunsolicited+application&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeculative%20application%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsolicited%20application%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply for a job without being asked in a related offer of such a position, you are filling out an **unsolicited application**. The employer did not ask (solicit) you to submit it.

[Unsolicited](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsolicited)  = *Not looked for* or requested; *unsought*: an unsolicited manuscript; unsolicited opinions.

Note that *unsolicited* does not mean unwanted:

> *Nothing is more welcome than an unsolicited complement.*

Comment: It's what we tought would be the ideal translation. But unsolicited has a negative connotation, that isnt there in french.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, reaching out to a company or prospective contact that has not solicited that contact is referred to as a **cold call** or **cold contact**. This term is often used to describe an attempt to sell a product or service to that company, but broadly speaking, inquiring about a job that may or may not exist is a way of offering your services.

See this blog about job searching, for example:

[A cold contact cover letter is a document sent with your resume to companies that have not advertised job openings](https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-a-cold-contact-cover-letter-2061946).

Comment: A cold call is more a think of marketing. I don't think it fits the context. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: As you like it. It is commonly used in marketing, but if you Google "cold calling for jobs," you will see it is commonly used in that context as well.